# Change Certain Value When I Detect Change in Vector

Tags: c++, vector

So, I have the following vector:

```
vector<int> vec = {2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9};
```

I have a value offset which starts at 0:

```
int offset = 0;
```

I want to go through the array and change the offset value accordingly. 
For example, if we started at the beginning (at the first 2), the I want

```
offset = 0;
```

And then, when it arrives at the second 2, I want

```
offset = -16;
```

But ONCE I see that the array value is no longer 2 (it changes), I want offset to reset to 0 (and then if it sees the next 3, it will become `offset = offset - 16`).

I want to keep subtracting 16 from my offset value as long as the value in the vector doesn't change while I iterate over it. But once I detect a change, I want to reset offset.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: and then when it arrives at the 2nd 2, I want `offset = -16;`. WUT?

Comment: Keep the previous value in a separate variable. If it's different from the current value, then do whatever you need to do, and set the previous value variable to the current value.

Comment: best way to do it? no clue. One way to do it? Write a loop that does just what you explain in words. Its a bit foggy what you expect as answer...

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.  The only thing I can think of that comes close is [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Answer (score 1):

This is just what you explain in words translated to code:

```
vector<int> vec = {2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9};
int offset = 0;
int current = vec[0];
for (unsigned i = 1; i< vec.size(); ++i) {
     if (vec[i] == current) offset -= 16;
     else                   offset = 0;
     current = vec[i];
 }
```

Though I dont really understand what this is supposed to be good for, or what you mean with "best way". However, the code was too much for a comment....

Comment: How do you handle the case when `vec` is empty?

Comment: @Ayxan I dont, the initialization is hard coded, why should I handle something that cannot happen?

Comment: It surely won't stay hard coded and adding at least a small note would be useful IMO

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int Test(const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    int offset = 0;
    int previous = vec.size() > 0 ? vec[0] : 0;
    for (auto &current : vec)
    {
        if (previous == current) offset -= 16;
        else offset = 0;
        previous = current;
    }
    return offset;
}


int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::cout << "None " << Test({}) << "\n";
    std::cout << "One " << Test({ 9 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Two Equal " << Test({ 9, 9 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Two Differnt " << Test({ 9, 8 }) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Many " << Test({ 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9 }) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

To find the best solution for you you should consider testing whatever solution you create so that you know it has the behavior you want. The output of this snippet can be inspected and you can check the individual tests with a debugger. Consider using a testing framework to preserve tests for the future.

Comment: `for each (auto &current in vec)` is that C# code in the middle of C++ code?

Comment: @Ayxan no that is a ranged c++ loop with an auto reference. Should be part of c++11 ish.

Comment: @Ayxan ah - i see you corrected it. So the previous had the for each syntax - i think that is some experimental feature in visual studio and i did not notice while autocompleting my way to happyness.

Comment: `each` is not valid c++, it won't compile that way

Comment: @Ayxan I compiled and ran it on VS2017 before posting. I am pretty sure though you are right about that not beeing c++ there. has to be some compiler specific extension.

Comment: Looks like yeah, that is the case. VS2017 output: `nonstandard extension 'for each' used: replace with ranged-for statement`. minGW output: `error: expected '(' before 'each'
     for each (auto &current in vec)`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want to *do* with `offset` or where you want to obtain it. But if you're just looking for a way to output it on a per element basis you could hack [`adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) or similar:

```
auto offset = 0;

cout << offset << ' ';
adjacent_find(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), [&](const auto lhs, const auto rhs){
    if(lhs == rhs) {
        offset -= 16;
    } else {
        offset = 0;
    }
    cout << offset << ' ';
    return false;
});
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mp6nv7)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd generalize this problem:

1. Pass it to a function by reference
2. Check if the vector is empty, if it is, throw an exception
3. Have a `for` loop, and declare `offset` **outside** it, so you can manually reset `offset` whenever you want.

Example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void gen_offset(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    if (vec.empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Vector is empty");
    }
    int offset = 0;
    int curr_val = vec[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i != vec.size(); ++i) {
        if (vec[i] == curr_val) {
            offset -= 16;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << curr_val << " => " << offset << std::endl;
            offset = 0;
            curr_val = vec[i];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                       5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9};
    gen_offset(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 => -16
3 => -32
4 => -96
5 => 0
6 => -16
8 => -176
```